# Replace text by clicking and store it for further clicking

Tags: android, textview, clickable

I am building an app for practicing of text memorization.
I have a textview, and I try to make each word clickable such that after clicking it, an underline would replace that word. Then clicking again the underline would restore the original word.

For example, given the verse:

> *"And the wolf shall dwell with the lamb, and the leopard shall lie down with the kid; and the calf and the young lion and the fatling together; and a little child shall lead them."*

Clicking on 'wolf' and 'lamb' leads to:
"And the ____ shall dwell with the ____, ..."
Clicking on the underlines restores the original words:
"And the **wolf** shall dwell with the **lamb**, ...".

---

What I've been able to do so far is the first half of the task:

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
String regex = "\\S+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    final String word = matcher.group();
    final int start = matcher.start();
    final int end = matcher.end();
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            try {
                Editable editable = (Editable) textView.getText();
                editable.replace(start, end, "____");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            //Remove default underline associated with spans
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can maintain boolean variable and update it as per your requirement. And you also need to create a string with dashes according to the length of the word that you want to replace in another function. Then with the basic setText() you can achieve whatever you want.

Does this help you?